# How to redirect from a post route to a get route in node.js

Tags: node.js

i am new to node js and was making a mini message board as a assignment. What I  want  to do is to redirect the user to localhost:3000/index from localhost:3000/new when  "submit" is pressed.I have tried using res.redirect but it is not working.

Here's the code:-

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'MINI-MESSAGE-BOARD',
    message: messages
  });
});

router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
  var userMessage=req.body.messagesName;
  var userName=req.body.userName;
  res.render('new');

  messages.push({
    name: userName,
    text: userMessage,
    date: new Date()
  });
  res.redirect('/index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have a messages array declared above.

I have also created a form in pug for new.js which is:

```
form(action="/new" method="POST" redirect="/index")
  input(type="text" placeholder="write something" name="userName")
  br
  br
  input(type="text" placeholder="write something" name="messagesName")
  button(value="SUBMIT")
```

I've tried giving a href to button(out of desperation)still didn't worked.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Express can't render a response and then redirect as they each send different HTTP response headers to the client. You can do one or the other.

Remove the `res.render()`

```
router.post('/new',function(req,res,next){
      var userMessage=req.body.messagesName;
      var userName=req.body.userName;

      messages.push({name:userName,text:userMessage,date: new Date()});
      res.redirect('/index');
});
```

Comment: If i remove res.render... the page will be redirected to /index but it will then not show the contents(the form) on /new. Is there a way i can achieve to take inputs from the /new and then redirect it to /index??

Comment: Thank you for helping. Just changed the get and post routes now its working.Thnak you Matt

Comment: @phantom The common way is to handle the `POST /new` in javascript so the browser never navigates away from `/index` in the first place (lookup AJAX).

Comment: In the apps existing request/response layout that's a bit harder. You could redirect the `/index` on the client side via javascript after displaying the "new" message. You could make `/new` render the `/index` content plus your message.

Comment: what I've done is that i've made a get new /route in which i render and post /new route in which i redirect.It worked for me.Same what you told me